# Sync identity account with AD password changes

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7

If I change an AD account's password which may be an IIS7 app-pool identity account, the app pool will not use the new password. IIS7 requires manually typed passwords, unlike software like SQL Server, where you can select user accounts and not "hard-enter" a password.

The above problem is probably a security concern and causes reliability issues. Is there a way to sync the identity (Which is a domain account) with AD so it picks up password changes?

Thanks

Comment: Why's the account's password changing without updating the app pool identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a managed service account.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356(WS.10).aspx

Comment: That points me in the right direction

Comment: Glad to help...